# how to get terminal properties

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

I very frequently work on multiple items in parallel and end up running some long tests or regression after working on something. I usually add a `mail -s "foo" id < /dev/null` at the end to know when a task ends so that I don't have to baby sit a long test or regression.

I was trying to automate this, where in I don't have to type the mail every time, just call a script (alias this to fewer characters - optimizing on how much I type) and the script figures out the test/regression from the cwd and sends an email. I thought it would be useful to send the terminal title or the screen session name in the email. Is there a way I can extract the terminal title or Linux screen window name?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the screen session name, when attached, in `$STY` (the window number is available in `$WINDOW` if you need it):

```
$ echo "$STY"
6367.sessionname
```

You can find the uniquely identifying tty/pty device with `tty`:

```
$ tty
/dev/pts/34
```

Titles and such are features of xterm and not of the terminal itself, so terminals programs have a hard time deducing it.

Here's an example using both of the above to show the screen name if any, or the tty device otherwise:

```
mail -s "${STY:-$(tty)} done" < /dev/null
```

Screen also has a "wait for silence" feature where you can get a notification when processes in other screen windows have stopped outputting.